# Checking Null in MySQL Nested If

Tags: mysql, json, if-statement

I am trying to write a MySQL function that pulls a value out of a text field that is formatted as a JSON dict.  However, for some reason I can't get the nested IF statement to work without syntax errors.

Here is the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS json_key;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `json_key`(`col` TEXT, `key` VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE pos INT;
    IF (col IS NULL) THEN SET ret = "";
    ELSEIF (col = "") THEN SET ret =  "";
    ELSEIF (LOCATE(key, col) = 0) THEN SET ret =  "";
    ELSE 
        SET pos := LOCATE(key, col);
        SET len := LENGTH(key);
        SET bg  := pos + len;
        SET ret = SUBSTR(col, bg, LOCATE('"', col, bg) - bg));
    END IF;
    RETURN ret;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'key, col) = 0) THEN SET ret =  "";

ELSE 
SET pos := LOCATE(key, col);
SET len :=' at line 7
```

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word.

Either use a different name, say `jKey` or use backticks (**`**) to get it accepted

**Change these lines**:

```
ELSEIF (LOCATE(key, col) = 0) THEN SET ret =  "";
ELSE 
    SET pos := LOCATE(key, col);
    SET len := LENGTH(key);
```

**To**:

```
ELSEIF (LOCATE(`key`, col) = 0) THEN SET ret =  "";
ELSE 
    SET pos := LOCATE(`key`, col);
    SET len := LENGTH(`key`);
```

**Refer to**:  [**MySQL Reserved Words**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis around the condition and check; like

```
ELSEIF LOCATE(key, col) = 0 THEN SET ret =  "";
```

You can as well change your condition checking like

```
IF (col IS NULL OR  col = "" OR LOCATE(key, col) = 0) THEN SET ret = "";
ELSE 
    SET pos := LOCATE(key, col);
    SET len := LENGTH(key);
    SET bg  := pos + len;
    SET ret = SUBSTR(col, bg, LOCATE('"', col, bg) - bg));
END IF;
```

Comment: Ravinder caught the error, but I voted up this one as well because it cleans up the overall structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET len := (coalesce(LENGTH(key),0));
```